# Convert SQL Server date to DB2 date

Tags: sql-server, db2

Here is db2 date format

```
 1190707 - CYYMMDD
```

I would like to be able to convert a SQL Server DATE to this format

I found out i can use

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMMdd')
```

but problem now is to get the 1st character which i have no idea what it is

Comment: Please tell us to what the value `1190707` corresponds.

Comment: correspondes to 2019 - 07 - 07    yyyy - mm - dd, i'm not sure what the 1st number is though

Comment: Why is there a `119` there?  Did you mean `0190707` ?

Comment: not sure what it is about, this is a format from a linked server database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C is a century digit. And it seems to be based on the 20th century, thus years starting with 19. For years starting with 20, the century digit is one and for the 20th century the century digit is omitted.

This should do the trick

```
DECLARE @DateToConvert AS DATE
SELECT @DateToConvert = GETDATE()
--SELECT @DateToConvert = DATEADD(year, -100, GETDATE())

SELECT
    CAST(
        CONCAT(
            CAST((DATEPART(YEAR, @DateToConvert)/1000) AS INT)-1, 
            FORMAT(@DateToConvert, 'yyMMdd')
        ) AS BIGINT)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this works

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMdd') - 19000000
```

Comment: This was simpler.